# Setting constrains at the bottom of the ConstraintLayout in Android

Tags: android, frame, android-constraintlayout

I would like to set a constraint for a FrameLayout to the top of the Navigation bar in Android.

Here is the code of the XML layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorGreen"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"


        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried it with the line:

> `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation`

but it the resulting layout does not seem to look rigth. Here you can see a screenshot:
[image]
Do you have any ideas what I should do? I'd appreciate every comment and would be thankful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

In your FrameLayout

Comment: Thanks Groky for your answer. It helped but I do not understand why the layout_height is 0 dp? 0dp basically means that it does not have any height, right? But this is obviously not the case. I'd appreciate further comments.

Comment: Why do I have to use 0dp as the layout_height?

Comment: Its because you are using a ConstraintLayout, so when u give a 0dp height or width, the view expands as much as possible to meet the constraints. For this case you need to give the correct constraints